# Access extract (Decompile)

Tags: ms-access

Does anybody knows how to extract an .ADP or .ADE access file?

Comment: ADP has protection? There are companies that claim to be able to reclaim ade vba file code, but they'll make you prove you own the IP.

Answer (score 0):

[MDE to MDB Conversion Service for Microsoft® Access](http://www.everythingaccess.com/mdeconversion.htm)
Wayne has stated he will require proof that you own the code.

Note that there are other free downloadable utilities and/or code to extract forms and reports however not the VBA code.   Queries and macros you can already extract from an MDE/ADE/ACCDE.